# Is it possible to run KVM-Accelerated VM on Android Devices?

Tags: kernel, development

I am trying to enable KVM on the Android kernel so that I can run KVM accelerated VM on my Android phone. However, after enabling KVM, checking the dmesg, I get this:

```
[    1.039716] c3       1 kvm [1]: HYP mode not available
```

Do you know why this is happening? Is it possible to somehow enable KVM on Android?

Comment: Related: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-stock-android-pie-kernel-with-kvm.3916145/

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious. [KVM/ARM](https://lwn.net/Articles/557132/) requires HYP mode - a special hardware support in CPU (virtualization extensions) - which is not available on your device, or your kernel is outdated. Kernel doc: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/Documentation/arm/booting.rst